# Pass variable when binding template

Tags: knockout.js, durandal

Currently I bind a template this way

```
 <div data-bind="template: { name: 'comp-template', foreach: company}">
```

Now I need to pass a variable `"host-company" = true` while binding the  template so that I can access that variable from comp-template view. How can I do this?

**Note:** currently I get company details from a json file and current view looks like this

```
 Host company: <span data-bind="if: text:host.company"></span>
```

This output to `Host company: true`. So I want something like this

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'comp-template', foreach: company, data: {host-company: text:host.company} }">
```

So that I can use the value of text:host.company in template as host-company.

Comment: what is `"host-company"` here? Is it a property inside the objects enclosed by the `company` array(like `company[0].hostCompany`)?

Comment: You can't have a "-" (dash) in your variable name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to remove the `-`(dash) from the `host-company` because that makes it an invalid identifier. I would suggest to rename it to `hostCompany` or something like this.

Assuming there is a property named - `hostCompany` which is a part of the objects inside of the `company` array, you can pass that variable inside of the `data` object wrapper like so -

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'comp-template', foreach: company, data: { hostCompany: hostCompany } }">
```

Or else like so -

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'comp-template', foreach: company, data: { hostCompany: true } }">
```

**EDIT**

Assuming that you have an object `host` (on the *root* level) having a boolean property named `company`, the value of which you want to pass to the template, you can do so like below -

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'comp-template', foreach: company, data: { hostCompany: host.company } }">
```

You can access this parameter inside your template as -

```
<!--ko if: hostCompany -->
    <span>Host company is true</span>
<!--/ko-->
```